# C++ - index array using temporary variable

Tags: c++, arrays, string, indexing

I am in the early stages of making a program in C++ that replaces integer input with its english counterpart. I do not want instructions on how make this program, but rather, insight to how a certain portion of the code behaves a certain way, and perhaps tips how to fix it.

```
std::string strToEng(std::string s)
{
  int sInt = atoi(s.c_str());


  std::string digit1[] = {"zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven",
                          "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen",
                          "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", 
                          "nineteen"};

  switch(s.size())
  {
    case 1:
    {
      int temp = int(s[0]);
      return digit1[temp];
    }
   }

  return "error";
}
```

The issue is with the digit1 array in the switch statement. When I compile this code, case 1 does not return the desired output. If I change digit1[temp] to some sort of constant(i.e. digit1[3]), it displays properly. Is there an issue with using a variable to index an array? How can I solve this?

EDIT:Perhaps deceptive that I have no way of handling digits higher than nine, yet they are still contained within digit1. The reason for this is that this code has been rewritten several times.

Comment: *"Is there an issue with using a variable to index an array?"* Lord, I hope not.

Comment: The problem looks like it has to do with your conversion `int(s[0])`. This to me looks like a cast, which simply interprets the bytes from char to int, and this depends on the ascii value. '1' is not the same as 1. You will want to use some method to convert that character to an int. (I see you already making use of atoi in your code)

Comment: `int temp = int(s[0]);`??? switch on s.size()??? This is not good.

Comment: Describe what you think `s.size()` does.  Describe what you think `int(s[0])` does.

Comment: If my code is faulty, I apologize. I want to figure this out by myself. I'll probably rewrite it if I think of something better.

Comment: @Porkbutts I guess the source of my confusion was that I couldn't use atoi directly on s[0]. I think I've got it sorted out now.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `digit1[sInt]` as you already converted the string into a int value...

`s[0]` is just the first char of the String, so if the first char is `'0'` then its value is 48 (see ASCII table), and then you access the 49-th element of your table... In your case 1, you can try `int(s[0])-'0'`, and it should work.

Comment: Ah, thank you! I didn't consider that. This seems to be the best solution. I am not using sInt for this purpose(in fact I thought I deleted it...), for the reason that I plan to expand this to handle multiple digits.

Comment: @Steven J Wayne Esq: atoi will already handle multiple digits for you.

Answer (score 0):

You cast the first character of s to an int so if s contains a digit, the value is in the range of ASCII values for the decimal digits which is 48 to 57. Why non use the int sInt you create correctly in the first line of your function?